# Trim a command terminal output-string using Python

Tags: python-3.x, trim, strip

I would like to trim this string:

```
MAC Address    IP Address      US             DS           MAC         Prim RxPwr  Timing Num  BPI
                               Intf           Intf         Status      Sid  (dBmv) Offset CPEs Enb
eca4.4051.3018 0.0.0.0         11/1.0w*       0/0/18*      online(pt)  1432 2.5    2444   1    yes
               2400:6cec:400:9:eea9:40ff:fe51:3018
online cm 1 ; offline cm 0 ; ranging cm 0
```

and only return: *2400:6cec:400:9:eea9:40ff:fe51:3018* as the output

what is the best way to go about trimming this string?

Comment: What logic would tell you which line of output you need?

Comment: I am using telnetlib, decoding it from ascii and converting to a string. Now I just need to trim/strip the excess to obtain only the ipv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

If the output format is fixed:

```
lines = "\n".split(this_string)
val = lines[3].replace(" ", "")
```

If the output format may vary, but you know the pattern that you wanted to retrieve (below I'm assuming that it's all hex and the number of digits are fixed):

```
match = re.match("[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{3}:[0-9a-f]:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}", this_string)
val = match.group()
```